# Trouble with counting characters

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, ascii, output

Hi all I have been tasked with writing a program that counts the number of 'a' characters in a sentence. The most complex code I can use is do while for loops and switch statements. This is the code I have so far. If I put the cout inside the do-while then it will say 123 etc but the cout's wont even show when they are after the do-while loop. I used the ascii table of values to determine the value for the letter a. I am having trouble with my output and would just appreciate some feedback.

```
int main()
{
char lettertofind;
int letteramt=0;

cout<<"Enter a sentence\n";
cin>>lettertofind;

do
{
   cin>>lettertofind;
   if(lettertofind == 65||97){
     letteramt++;
    }
}while(lettertofind != '\n');

cout<<"There are"<<letteramt<<" a's in that sentence"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use that :/

Answer (score 1):

Do:`if(lettertofind == 65|| lettertofind == 97){`

Since `97` (or anything that is not 0 or "false") is considered to be `true` so your condition was always evaluated to be true.

For example doing something like `while(97){}` will create an infinite loop (it's exactly like `while(true){}`

Comment: better yet use 'a' and 'A' instead of 97 and 65

Comment: ive tried these steps however my code does not output anything

Answer (score 0):

`if(lettertofind == 65||97)` should read `if(lettertofind == 65|| lettertofind == 97)`.
Also you can remove `cin>>lettertofind;` before `do`.

But this is not a single issue. Your code will read only a single character as `lettertofind` is declared with the `char` type. But you request from user to type in a whole sentence. I suggest to change `lettertofind` to be of the `string` type and then to read a whole line from user input. The code can be something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string lettertofind;
int letteramt=0;

cout<<"Enter a sentence\n";

// cin>>lettertofind;
 getline(cin, lettertofind);
 for(int i=0;i<lettertofind.size();i++)
   if(lettertofind[i] == 'a' || lettertofind[i] == 'A'){
     letteramt++;
   }

cout<<"There are "<<letteramt<<" a's in that sentence"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use the getline command any idea how to work around that?